# Is there the same router for Vue like angular ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there the same router for Vue like angular ui-router? What router is the best for Vue?

Answer (score 1):

vue-router is the offical router for Vue

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router

https://router.vuejs.org/

You could also build your own if you want to understand how your router is working:

https://vueschool.io/articles/tutorials/creating-your-own-router/86/

Comment: I find vue router far less advanced than ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

[Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/). That should keep you happy :-)